# Pregunta TEMPLATES html5 css js [Urgente ayuda]

Tags: html

Buenas noches, tengo unas dudas que espero que alguno de ustedes me pueda ayudar a solucionar!

-
Mi papa tiene un instituto de idiomas, con 450 almunos, dicta cursos online etc, se utiliza MUCHO la pagina, pero la pagina es PESIMA ( www.iesdr.edu.ar )
Lo que tenia en mente es comprar 2 templates, una para la pagina principal y otra template que sirviera una vez ingresados con la cuenta de cada usuario y para el panel admin de la pagina del instituto.
El panel admin es un DESASTRE! pesima organizacion, y muy feo..

Les dejo la foto del panel de admin
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zGdo.png

Esta es la template que quiero comprar para el inicio de la pagina

> > > >
> > >       https://themeforest.net/item/educampus-education-university-html-template/11453628?_ga=2.14725110.1529125352.1516261028-328738516.1516261028

Esta es la template que quiero comprar para el panel admin

> > > >
> > >       https://themeforest.net/item/swift-university-responsive-material-admin-template-for-school-colleges/19535863?s_rank=3
> > >       o
> > >       https://themeforest.net/item/elite-admin-the-ultimate-dashboard-web-app-kit-material-design/16750820?s_rank=2

Y queria ver que tan posible era mi idea, sin tener que cambiar el link de la pagina original ( www.iesdr.edu.ar )
Mis preguntas son:
1- Es posible realizar el cambio? Existe algun problema?
2- No va a haber problema con la base de datos, es decir con las cuentas de los estudiantes, profesores, admins?
3- Es posible actualizar ese panel admin, en la nueva interfaz esa?
4- Con respecto a la interfaz del inicio, no habra problema con el tema del login para usuarios?

Espero su respuesta, realmente va a ser muy util para mi, y voy a estar muy agradecido!
Les agradezco, saludos desde Laguna Beach!

Comment: Mientras que conectes todos los datos del template con los que extraiga de la base de datos, o conectes ese nuevo login, con la base de datos, no sucederá nada en tu contra.

Comment: y si quieres, no haría falta comprar, solo descargar el html, js, css de todas las paginas y añadirles tu propio php o conectar a la base de datos propio

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1):

> Es posible realizar el cambio?

Si

> Existe algun problema?

Podría presentarse que el código PHP y el HTML están horriblemente mezclados.
El riesgo principal es que borres código PHP que es necesario para el funcionamiento del sitio.

> 2- No va a haber problema con la base de datos, es decir con las cuentas de los estudiantes, profesores, admins?

No, la base de datos seguirá intacta.

> 3- Es posible actualizar ese panel admin, en la nueva interfaz esa?

Si, podría presentarse que el código PHP y el HTML están horriblemente mezclados. El riesgo principal es que borres código PHP que es necesario para el funcionamiento del sitio.

> 4- Con respecto a la interfaz del inicio, no habra problema con el tema del login para usuarios?

No, ya que los datos están alojados en la base de datos.

**Consejo:**  Hazte un duplicado de ese sitio en tu computadora (entorno de desarrollo) Ve haciendo los cambios y haciendo pruebas.

Answer (score 0):

Mira por lo que he leído de tu pregunta, es posible realizar la migración del sitio a una nueva template.

Pero como dice: @Reynald0 en la pagina actual tienes mucho código php y html mal mezclado y organizado.

Lo cual al querer migrar a la template se te va a hacer mucho despelote y confusión a la hora de re-organizar el código.

Lo que te sugiero es:

> Realizar una copia del sitio actual (siempre es importante)
>
> Utilizar una de esas copias y eliminar todo el HTML (o casi todo). Para poder utilizar el código PHP que es el que le dará funcionamiento al sitio.
>
> Y por ultimo, migrar / pasar el código PHP según el diseño/template del sitio que quieras comprar.

Cualquiera de las dos templates, tanto normal como para admin se pueden utilizar, ya que son "gráficas" y no funcionales como el código PHP.

Por otra parte, sino sabes de programación, contactaria a un equipo para hacer la migración ya que lleva bastante tiempo y puede presentar fallas.